# NTLM and Golang

Tags: curl, go, ntlm

I have recently learnt Go and I am experimenting with the `net/http` library. I have been trying to authenticate into a site using the `http.SetBasicAuth` function but it never seems to work. It works fine with `cURL` but not with Go. I know this has something to do with `NTLM` but I don't know how to fix the problem

cURL:

`curl -v "http://server_that_im_trying_to_auth_with" --ntlm -u user:pass`

Go:

```
 req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "url", nil)
 req.SetBasicAuth(user, pass)
 resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
 body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

The body keeps on returning the sites 401 Page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NTLM Authentication and Basic Authentication are not the same. NTLM is a protocol which is more complicated than just user:password string in header.
If you want to make a request from Golang code to authenticate you should use one of existing libraries, like: [go-ntlmssp](https://github.com/Azure/go-ntlmssp)

Also you can read more about NTLM protocol itself [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236621.aspx)